# create png/jpg from random byte[]

Tags: java, android

I was wondering if it is possible to create a byte array that can be decoded to a Bitmap.

For example, suppose I have a byte array of 100 elements. Could I somehow transform it into an image? I read about headers and whatnots for png, and markers for jpges, but I'm still rather clueless ...

Maybe take 4 bytes at a time and create pixels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question: **"create png/jpg from random byte[]"**; literally possible though not directly: 
You will have to use your own logic first to create a `Bitmap` `Object` from that `byte[]`. But along with the `byte[]` you will also need to have the bitmaps **width**, **height** and **bytes per pixel** (`Bitmap.Config`) predefined. You will also have to ensure the size of the byte[] matches the predefined values or accept the blank space in the Bitmap, i.e.:

```
byte[] b = new byte[width*height*bytesPerPixel];
```

...so **100** bytes could give you a **5 X 5** pixel bitmap with 4 bytes per pixel. Then you create a `Bitmap` `Object`:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.create(width, height, Bitmap.Config.<whatever>)
```

...where **<whatever>** will depend on **bytes per pixel**. Example for 4 bytes per pixel it would be `ARGB_8888`.

Then run through every pixel in `bitmap` using two `for` loops, and pull out `bytesPerPixel` (assuming 4 now) number of bytes from `b`, generate a pixel colour and draw the pixel to it:

```
// Create a Canvas Object;
Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);
// Value to index the byte[];
int bI = 0;
// Paint Object for drawing the pixel;
Paint p = new Paint();
// Iterate through the pixel rows;
for(int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    // Iterate through the pixels in the row;
    for(int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        // Pull out 4 bytes and generate colour int;
        // This entire statement depends on bytesPerPixel;
        int colorInt = Color.argb(b[bI++], b[bI++], b[bI++], b[bI++]);
        // Set the colour on the Paint;
        p.setColor(colorInt);
        // Draw the pixel;
        c.drawPoint(j, i, p);
    }
}
```

Now your `Bitmap` will be present in memory so to save it to a file:

```
try {
    // Create a File Object;
    File file = new File(<file path>)
    // Ensure that the file exists and can be written to;
    if(!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
    }
    // Create a FileOutputStream Object;
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    // Write the Bitmap to the File, 100 is max quality but
    //        it is ignored for PNG since that is lossless;
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos)
    // Clear the output stream;
    fos.flush();
    // Close the output stream;
    fos.close();
} catch (Exception e) {}
```